# 'UIPopoverController' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have developed a project that shows error :

> 'UIPopoverController' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIPopoverController is deprecated. Popovers are now implemented as UIViewController presentations. Use a modal presentation style of UIModalPresentationPopover and UIPopoverPresentationController.

My codings are:

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Photos/Photos.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>



@interface ViewController : UIViewController
 <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

- (IBAction)touch:(id)sender;

@end

@interface SecondView : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>



//video gallery
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIPopoverPresentationController *popOver;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *studentView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *videoURL;


@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
- (void)openGallery {

UIImagePickerController *Picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
Picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
Picker.mediaTypes=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,  nil];
Picker.delegate=self;

if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

{


    UIPopoverController *popController=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:Picker];
    [popController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 600, 160, 300) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    self.popOver=popController;
}
else
{
    [self presentViewController:Picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}


#pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


if (self.studentView) {

    self.videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[self.videoURL absoluteString] forKey:@"url1"];
}

}
```

I could not proper reference for UiModalPresentationPopover. Can someone help me to solve this error. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

> use  **UIModalPresentationPopover**
>
> In a horizontally regular environment, a
>   presentation style where the content is displayed in a popover view.
>   The background content is dimmed and taps outside the popover cause
>   the popover to be dismissed. If you do not want taps to dismiss the
>   popover, you can assign one or more views to the passthroughViews
>   property of the associated UIPopoverPresentationController object,
>   which you can get from the popoverPresentationController property.
>
> In a horizontally compact environment, this option behaves the same as
>   UIModalPresentationFullScreen.
>
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

Reference [UIModalPresentationStyle Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIModalPresentationStyle)

for example

```
ModalViewController *modal = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
modal.transitioningDelegate = self;
modal.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
modal.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectZero;
modal.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:modal animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**else use UIPopoverPresentationController**

for example

```
UIPopoverPresentationController *popController = [self. popoverPresentationController];
popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
popController.barButtonItem = self.leftButton;
popController.delegate = self;
```

additional [reference](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-create-popovers-in-ios-9/)

Comment: The above not navigating to the screens while on clicking the labels available insde the popover.

[popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.titleView.frame inView:self.navigationController.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];